# Looping through JSON with NewtonSoft

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, json.net

There are over 6,300 messages in my JSON file.  My JSON is formatted like so...

```
{ "messages":[
  {
    "id": ...
  }
...
]}
```

I'm trying to loop through each message in this JSON file using NewtonSoft using this code...

```
Dim jObj As JObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(outputJSONpath & "myFileName.json"))
Dim jArr As New JArray(jObj("messages"))
For Each message As JObject In jArr.Children(Of JObject)()
    'Do work
Next
```

When I do a `jArr.Children(Of JObject)().Count` I get 0.  I would expect to see the count at 6,300.  When in the immediate window I see a valid object for jObj and jArr.  I've successfully used code very similar to this before, but I can't figure out what's wrong here.  I verified my JSON is valid at jsonlint.com thinking maybe I had corrupt JSON.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `messages` is a JArray you just need to cast it:

```
Dim jArr As JArray = CType(jObj("messages"), JArray)
```

Comment: Thank you @kblok!  You nailed it!

Comment: @kblock For Each message As JObject In jarr.Children(Of JObject)()
                Dim threadID = message.SelectToken("thread_ID") it's telling me message is not declared.

Comment: Why don't you try just looping this `For Each message As JObject In jarr`?

Comment: Same result.  message is not declared.

Comment: Tested locally, It's `jArr.Values()` :)

Comment: Using jArr.Values() i get this error:  "Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'."

Comment: I tried casting it like this For Each message As JObject In jArr.Values(Of JObject)() but then I get message is not declared again.

Comment: I'm not so familiarized with VB.NET, this using `var`s in C# does all the trick for you `foreach(var message in jArr.Values())`